# button and form to change src of Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, iframe

I'm building a page that I want a form to be able to target the iframe and have the selected webpage be what displays in the iframe.

I'm only needing the iframe to display an external webpage, and a button to make it happen. Not actually passing any information form or to the form. 
Thanks

EDIT:  After the Information I learned here, and a few Google searches to expound on that knowledge I came up with this, it works nicely.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Check Port 1935</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="resultsFrame" src="http://helpdesk.mydomain.com/test/prompt.html" name=resultsFrame width="500" height="300"></iframe>
            <p>The page will display information about Wowza if the port is open<br>
            The page will time out after ~20 seconds or so if the port is closed</p>
        <form id="frmTestRegion" method="GET">
            <select id="SelectRegion" name="SelectRegion">
                <option value="http://helpdesk.mydomain.com/test/prompt.html"></option>
                <option value="http://ipaddress1:port/">USA</option>
                <option value="http://ipaddress2:port/">Europe</option>
                <option value="http://ipaddress3:port/">Australia</option>
                <option value="http://ipaddress4:port/">Japan</option>
                <option value="http://ipaddress5:port/">South America</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="testRegion();"/>Test Server</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="refreshIframe('http://helpdesk.mydomain.com/test/prompt.html');">Refresh Results</button>
        </form>
        <script>
            function testRegion() {
                var my_select = document.getElementById("SelectRegion");        
                var new_url = my_select.options[my_select.selectedIndex].value;
                document.getElementById('resultsFrame').src = new_url;
            }
            function refreshIframe(myurl) {
                document.getElementById('resultsFrame').src = myurl;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then i have the page at http://helpdesk.mydomain.com/test/prompt.html display this

```
Please select a server from the drop down menu</br>
Then click "Test Server"</br>
```

I learned a lot here, about how scripts and buttons work. 
Thanks

Comment: What is the reason you want the results in an iframe?

Comment: The page that will display in the iframe is only a line or 2 of text. It indicates that the client viewing the webpage can receive data from that server on that port.  ie, mywebserver.com:1935

Comment: Ok remove the jQuery library and the script and see my original answer.

Comment: I have edited the code, but nothing is displaying in the iframe. I checked for basic syntax, but to no avail. Any ideas? Thanks for all the help.  I ran the developer console, f12 and i get this `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined` Also is there a way to display a message if the page doesn't load?

Comment: Copy paste error on my part, function updated!

Comment: What does the iframe look like when the port is closed?

Comment: Well a little background, this is to test the clients port status, to see if they can request information on port 1935. So if the port is closed the iframe takes about 20-30 seconds, then displays to generic "page cannot be displayed" per the browser the client is using.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your additions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I updated my original question and marked your answer as correct.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to make things easier give your iframe an ID first:

```
<iframe id="resultsFrame" name=resultsframe></iframe>
```

Then in your function:

```
<script>
    function testRegion() {
        var my_select = document.getElementById("SelectRegion");        
        var new_url = my_select.options[my_select.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById('resultsFrame').src = new_url;
    }
</script>
```

And your "submit" button (changing it to a button element will prevent it from actually submitting the form, which we don't need to do since we're just firing a function):

```
<button type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="testRegion();"/>Test Server</button>
```

EDIT (Responding to Updates in Question):

Regarding the issue with your refreshing the iframe button/function, the problem is your button. When a button is in a form, it will default to a submit button. So when you click it, it actually submits the form, and since you have no action specified on the form, it defaults to the same page. The query string in your URL is the form submission data. To prevent a button in a form from submitting when it is clicked, change its type attribute to "button":

```
<button type="button" onclick="refreshIframe();">Refresh Results</button>
```

Regarding a custom error message when the iframe fails to load the source -- browser security restrictions will prevent you from accessing the contents of the iframe. There isn't much you can do from the parent page to edit the iframe innards if you're loading a domain different from the requesting domain. I'd suggest creating a new server-side script as a "proxy", then have that script do the work of checking the URL to see if its open/closed, and return a response to your iframe. So instead of applying the source URL to the iframe directly, you'd source your own server-side script "mydomain.com/test-url.php?src=ipaddress1" and return the error from your own script.